# Generate a new sentence from a given sentence without changing the meaning of the given sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, spacy

I want to generate new sentence from a given sentence which mean the same as the given sentence.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from random import randint
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
import nltk.data

# Load a text file if required
text = "How many holidays do I have?" 
output = ""
Lisst=[]
a=10
while (len(Lisst)<a):
    output = ""
    # Load the pretrained neural net
    tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

    # Tokenize the text
    tokenized = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    #print('tokenized',tokenized,'\n')

    # Get the list of words from the entire text
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    #print('words',words,'\n')
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    #print('stop_words',stop_words,'\n')

    # Identify the parts of speech
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)

    for i in range(0,len(words)):
        replacements = []


        # Only replace nouns with nouns, vowels with vowels etc.
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(words[i]):
            #print(syn)
            # Do not attempt to replace proper nouns or determiners
            if tagged[i][1] == 'NNP' or tagged[i][1] == 'DT':
                #print('tag',tagged[i][1])
                break

            # The tokenizer returns strings like NNP, VBP etc
            # but the wordnet synonyms has tags like .n.
            # So we extract the first character from NNP ie n
            # then we check if the dictionary word has a .n. or not 
            word_type = tagged[i][1][0].lower()
            #print('type',word_type)
            if syn.name().find("."+word_type+"."):
                # extract the word only
                #print('synname',syn.name().find("."+word_type+"."))
                r = syn.name()[0:syn.name().find(".")]
                #print(r)
                replacements.append(r)
                #print(replacements,'\n')

        if len(replacements) > 0:
            # Choose a random replacement
            replacement = replacements[randint(0,len(replacements)-1)]
            output = output + " " + replacement
            #print(output)
        else:
            # If no replacement could be found, then just use the
            # original word
            output = output + " " + words[i]
            #print('\n',output)

    #print('Input:',text)
    Lisst.append(output)
    #print('Output:',output)
    Lisst1=set(Lisst)
    Lisst=list(Lisst1)
    #print('Outputs',Lisst)
print('Input:',text)
print('Outputs',Lisst)
```

After browsing for a while I found this code and made few changes to it. And the output that I get is as follows:

```
Input: How many holidays do I have?
Outputs [' How many vacation bash iodine have ?', ' How many vacation dress one have ?', ' How many vacation dress i give_birth ?', ' How many vacation suffice i have ?', ' How many holiday do one have ?', ' How many holiday doctor_of_osteopathy i have ?', ' How many vacation do i have ?', ' How many vacation suffice one own ?', ' How many vacation do iodine rich_person ?', ' How many vacation cause i induce ?']
```

It changes the synonyms for all the words except DT determiner and NNP  proper noun, singular. Most of the output produced are meaning less. I want the output to be meaning full. 
And it will be great if I can generate a completely new sentence meaning the same. For Example:

```
Input: How many holidays do I have?
Outputs['Number of leaves do I have','Leaves that I can avail'.......,'']
```

Referral links are also welcomed.

Thanks in Advance :-).

Comment: I am stuck on a similar task. Did you find any solution to it? or if you could guide towards a path. Thanks in advance

Comment: I was not able to find a solution but you can check the link which was a bit helpful for me [link](https://archive.arisuchan.jp/%CE%BB/src/1498631886858-0.pdf). If you don't want to rephrase the sentence and just want to replace the words in the sentence with best matching synonyms then check out on wup_similarity.  If you come up with a better approach please share the details. :-)

Comment: Thank you @Gnaneshwar Babu this is really helpful

Comment: How do you measure the meaningfulness of a sentence?  Until you can define the meaningfulness of a sentence, you have no basis for selecting an appropriate response?